# Solr throwing java.lang.noclassdeffounderror on custom parser jar

Tags: java, solr

I have placed my custom jar [screenshot of jar dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHZc.png) in the `*Corename/lib/TNParser.jar` directory.

I have included the necessary reference in the solrconfig.xml for the JAR file and class name.

The JAR is correctly picked up by Solr when I restart the core, however as soon as I use the following command to search in the solr core dashboard I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the first external class that is being invoked in my code.

The said the JAR is working correctly in my local command line and even on my friend's system which makes me think the error is on the Solr side.

Here's the log file after I invoke the search

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cRY4.png)

Edit: Here's the code I added SolrConfig.xml

[Defined query parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZhsR.png)

[requesthandler definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrrIo.png)

Comment: Are you sure Solr's class loader (the standard doesn't, as far as I know) supports loading jars from inside your jar? Try to add the dependencies externally instead.

Comment: I was not aware that Standard Solr's ClassLoader doesn't handle jars within jars. How should I go about making these dependencies external?

Comment: I'd add them all to a dedicated directory, then have a `<lib dir="/path/to/your/directory" regex=".*\.jar" />` in my `sorlconfig.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I'll try doing this and update here. Just a quick question, will it not be a problem having the external dependencies in both the jar file(custom parser) and the lib folder for solr ?